# Type Conversion with a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary in Python that looks like the following:

```
result = {'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', '11.99', '89'), 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', '15.99', '85'), ... }
```

I am trying to convert the numbers into ints and floats, respectively. I am getting this error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` (referring to the `float` conversion).

There is probably something really small to fix here, but I am just missing it. Thanks in advance!

```
for keys in result: 
    result[keys][1] = float(result[keys][1]) 
    result[keys][2] = int(result[keys][2]) 
    print(result[keys])
```

Comment: The problem that you report is unrelated to your code. It comes from some other place. The real problem is that you attempt to modify a tuple, and tuples are immutable.

Comment: Hint: try lists instead of tuples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try something like this. Using your code I also got an error about assigning to tuples

```
for keys in result:
    result[keys] = (result[keys][0], float(result[keys][1]), int(result[keys][2]))
    print(result[keys])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since tuples are immutable, you have to reconstruct each tuple in the dictionary by applying the corresponding transforming functions to each item in the tuple. There is no need to call `str`, but doing so makes the solution uniform and easily extendable.

```
transformers = str, float, int
for key in result:
    result[key] = tuple(f(val) 
                    for f,val in zip(transformers, result[key]))
#{'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', 11.99, 89), 
# 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', 15.99, 85)}
```

**Note**: This is not the fastest solution. I present it solely to illustrate some unorthodox ways of solving problems with Python.